# Android: can't have two addTextChangedListener for two EditText?

Tags: android, crash, android-edittext

I am trying to make two EditText where I type anything in one of the EditText, the text I typed will be shown on the other EditText.

```
private EditText input_a;
private EditText input_b;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    input_a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_a);
    input_b = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_b);
    input_a.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    input_b.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v,boolean hasFocus) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==input_a && hasFocus){
        input_a.setText("");
        input_b.setText("");
        input_a.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                input_b.setText(input_a.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

    }else if(v==input_b && hasFocus){
        input_b.setText("");
        input_a.setText("");
        input_b.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                input_a.setText(input_b.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }
```

So when I type in the input_a, it works fine, the text I input is shown in input_b, however, when I type in the input_b, the application close unexpectedly. I don't see why the two blocks of codes are really similar but only one of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably getting a stack overflow (ironic isn't it)?

The problem is that when input_a gets focus, you are adding a TextChangedListener and in that listener you set the contents for input_b. This works just fine.

However, when focus changes to input_b, you add a TextChangedListener to input_b but you still have the TextChangedListener for input_a as well. Now when you type into input_b it changes the contents of input_a which triggers its TextChangeListener which changes the contents of input_b. This triggers the TextChangedListener for input_b and you just continue this cycle.

Comment: I think so, that may explain why I got a series of error message which seems like an infinite loop. Thank you so much! I tried the removeTextChangedListener before adding the new TextChangedListener and it works!

Answer (score 0):

What was the error message in LogCat? Find the one that relates back to your code.
Cliff